# Retrieving user id with custom method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've written a GetUserId method to do... the obvious. It should take username as a parameter and return a value of UserId.

It goes like this:

```
public long GetUserId(string username)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            var da =
                new SqlDataAdapter("Select UserId from Users where UserName=username", con);
        }            
    }
```

Please help me to correctly query the database and actually be able to return a value of type long so I could use it somewhere else.

Comment: Have you not tried Googling? There are LOTS of examples out there to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public long GetUserId(string username)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            var da =
                new SqlDataAdapter("Select UserId from Users where UserName=username", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);                
            return (long)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, tried this, but it wouldn't cast. I think there should be used some other classes besides SqlDataAdapter. I googled, but didn't find just what I need.

Comment: I've come up with something like this and it failed. Thank you for your version, but it somehow retrieves the username instead of userId throwing a SqlException.

Comment: One last amendment 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Sorry again, but figured as much. Done, but didn't work.